# Showing different forms on Radio Button selected

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have a grid with two column the first column have 3 radio button (Form 1, Form 2, Form 3). I want the second column to change forms or to display different windows depending on what radio button the user chooses.

Should I have them all placed upon each other and make them hidden, and then depending on what the user chooses I unhide it? or any other suggestions?

Comment: do you have some event or method where call display form?

Comment: please share some code, it is easier to help this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collapse all of them except the one selected, when switching radio buttons, make the other view visible, and collapse the displayed one.
Make sure you use MVVM for WPF, this will make everything easier to program